# Is there a vim colour scheme that looks like Aptana's?

Tags: vim, colors

I'm in the process of migrating from Aptana to Vim, and one thing that I really miss is Aptana's excellent colour scheme for Python.

Does anyone know of a vim colour scheme that is similar to Aptana's?

(I've looked [here](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/), but I haven't found one that comes close. A lot of chaff to sift through in that gallery.)

Comment: What's the name of the theme in Aptana?

Comment: Aptana just lists it as "Aptana Studio", rather unimaginatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aptana works with TextMate themes (`*.tmTheme`) which can be converted to the Vim format with an online tool.

1. Go to Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes.
2. Choose your theme, say "Aptana".
3. Click on <kbd>Export</kbd> and save `Aptana Studio.tmTheme` where you want.
4. Upload it to [Coloration](http://coloration.sickill.net/).
5. Choose "Vim color scheme".
6. Click on <kbd>Convert!</kbd>.
7. Paste the result in a new file: `~/.vim/colors/aptana.vim`.

Comment: This sounded like what I needed, but Coloration failed to process the .tmTheme file, and looking at the github tracker I found this comment: "coloration sets highlighting colors using #rrggbb format which is not supported by regular vim in terminal, only graphical vim versions..."

Comment: See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/P1Pp86xB): not only it processes `Aptana Studio.tmTheme` successfully but it also converts colors to work **both** in 256colors-capable terminal emulators (`ctermbg=248`) *and* GVim/MacVim (`guibg=#a7a7a7`). As I see it, this tool and the process I've detailed above are the only practical solution to your "problem" and, judging by the `:color aptana` I've just typed in Vim, a very effective one.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/wAszV.png) It's CLI Vim, running in Gnome terminal on Ubuntu 10.10. On the left is the original theme exported from Aptana, on the right is the Vim colorscheme as processed by Coloration (with the name changed by hand) and the active colorscheme is `aptana`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I'm not sure why Coloration is failing for me; it still gives me the error "This file doesn't look like xml plist file containing Textmate theme.". I appreciate you doing the legwork on this one :)

Comment: What version of Aptana do you use? Mine (downloaded yesterday from http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) is `Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.9.201202141038`.

Comment: I'm on 3.0.9.201202140953, which looks like it was built a mere 45 minutes before yours...

Comment: Could you paste your tmTheme somewhere?

Comment: I've uploaded the .tmTheme file [here](http://pastebin.com/UXP0YQT3).

Comment: Well, it's the exact same as mine but mine worked and yours didn't. Weird. You should probably report this bug to the author.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've found [jellybeans](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/jellybeans.vim), which comes fairly close (although it's a bit more colourful than Aptana's theme in some cases).